# Line up caret with link?

Tags: javascript

This works great for separating the caret from the link, making the link go to a page and the caret to trigger the drop-down. My only problem is making the caret line up with the link - it pulls right but drops below. How can I make it line up vertically with the link?

Here's the code:

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="shoes-15-05-03.html">SHOES</a>
  <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown"></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="">Boots and Booties</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Comfort</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: putting things in perspective : http://www.bootply.com/fLyNH5y4qj

Comment: you may be using the wrong word here. Do you mean the bullets in your bullet point list? (The term [caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) simply means the character `^`, which you're not using, or the marker for where text input will be inserted in a stretch of text, which seems unrelated to your question)

Comment: on an HTML note: don't use `<a href="#">`, that's an HTML 3.2 concept that in HTML4 and HTML5 means "navigate to the top of the page". It has **not** meant "not-active link" for 15 years now (you probably never heard that before, so best to hear it now). If you need a real link to a real page, use `<a href="...">`, but otherwise if you just need a clickable thing, *use `<button>`*, with CSS styling that just styles it as plain text (that's how browsers make buttons: an inline text element with CSS borders and background, and an `:active` rule to make them look fancy when you click them)

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just move the caret inside `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="shoes-15-05-03.html">SHOES<span class="caret"></span></a>
```